# ALTER command in Core data Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, core-data, alter-table

Is it possible to ALTER core data structure like in Sqlite 3.

My app is in app store with a specific structure. Now I want to add a new attribute(column) to the existing core data table. Is there any way to alter the table without DELETING?

May be a repeated question, but didn't find exact answers.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking to do is possible, and it is accomplished with model versioning and data migration.

The following reference from Apple is a good place to start. [Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html)